# Assigning values within a function in R and plugging in string values without quotes

Tags: r, function

I have the following data:

```
tdata <- structure(list(sno = list("koko012", "koko013", "koko014", "koko015", 
    "koko016", "koko017"), ko = c("DuunWaan", "ChoYo", "GyeongHaa", 
"JaeSeok", "HangJii", "CheonYuu"), en = c("Judge", "Flutting Flag", 
"Javelin of Sky", "Seat for Longevity", "Oar for visitor", "Milk of Sky"
), zh = c("庫樓", "", "梗河", "帝席", "", "天乳"), connect = list(
    c("1", "68933", "71352"), c("1", "71075", "71075"), c("2", 
    "72105", "71284", "71284", "71053"), c("2", "70602", "69226", 
    "69226", "67480"), c("6", "69612", "70327", "70327", "70400", 
    "70400", "69389", "69389", "68707", "68707", "68498", "68498", 
    "69612"), c("1", "77516", "77516"))), .Names = c("sno", "ko", 
"en", "zh", "connect"), row.names = 12:17, class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to write a function to help me input values into the empty `zh` cells found by a match in the `ko` column.

The following code doesn't seem to work.

```
u <- function(x, y){tdata$zh[grep(x, tdata$ko, ignore.case = T)] <- y}
u("choyo", "加油")
```

However, when I use the command independently, it works just fine.

```
tdata$zh[grep("choyo", tdata$ko, ignore.case = T)] <- "加油"
```

Where did I go wrong?

Another 'by the way' question would be: Could there be any way to use the u() function without the quote for strings?

Comment: You might want to read Hadley Wickham's [book chapter on functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html). It has a section on [replacement functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#replacement-functions) which implement the "modification in place" that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't go wrong. R doesn't pass arguments by reference like you seem to expect (actually it might be a little more subtle than that since you didn't pass the dataframe as an argument).

When you modify the `zh` column of `tdata` in the body of the function, you're actually modifying a copy of `tdata`.

You could fix this with:

```
u <- function(x, y){
  tdata$zh[grep(x, tdata$ko, ignore.case = T)] <- y
  tdata
}
tdata <- u("choyo", "加油")
```

The second line in the body of the function (`tdata`) is equivalent to a return statement. If it is more familiar to you, you could write `return(tdata)` instead, to return this modified copy.

Then we assign the output of the function to `tdata` in the global environment.

With regards to your "by the way" question, you could use the "deparse-substitute" pattern, like this:

```
u_2 <- function(x, y){
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y <- deparse(substitute(y))
  tdata$zh[grep(x, tdata$ko, ignore.case = T)] <- y
  tdata
}
u_2(choyo, 加油)
```

Comment: What does the `return` statement do? Why don't we have to use it when passing a function with only one variable? Ex: `p <- function(q){tdata$zh[grep(q,tdata$ko, ignore.case = T)]} p("choyo")`

Comment: Oh, I get it now. We are not modifying anything in `tdata` in the above example, therefore the `return` statement is not needed. It really has nothing to do with how many variables there are in a function.

Comment: In the absence of a `return()` statement, an R function returns the result of whatever expression is executed last (typically the last line). It has nothing to do with the number of arguments.

Comment: I'll change my title to "Assigning values within a function" to reflect the nature of my question.

Comment: Just so you know, there is a `<<-` function that assigns in calling environment if variable not found in function environment, but its usage is discouraged because it can be a source of bugs. So technically, `u <- function(x, y){
  tdata$zh[grep(x, tdata$ko, ignore.case = T)] <<- y
} ; 
u("choyo", "加油")` would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass the data frame to the function, so all parameters are passed to the function.

```
u <- function(dtf, x, y){
         dtf$zh[grep(x, dtf$ko, ignore.case = T)] <- y
         return(dtf)
}
u(dtf = tdata, x = "choyo", y = "blabla")
```